# BigQuery GetQueryResultsResponse.getPageToken() returns null when BigQuery Table is getting inserts by another application

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table with millions of records.

I am able to paginate using the `GetQueryResultsResponse.getPageToken()` method. The getPageToken is returning null if the underlying BigQuery Table is getting new inserts. The pageToken works fine if there are no inserts happening.

How to avoid this and be able to traverse the table even when inserts are happening on the bigquery table?

I am using google-api-services-bigquery v2-rev330-1.22.0"

Answer (score 1):

Not clear, but I think you are talking about tables.list pagination (*query result cannot have records streaming into it*)

In such cases  - instead of pageToken you can use [startIndex](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/list#startIndex) (along with [maxResults](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/list#maxResults))
Knowing items count in response (real page size) you can always calculate starting Index for next page to request (without using pageToken).
Having some extra management around those start Index in your app - you can manage paging in both directions (Next and Prev).
And of course you can always manage navigation to :
First Page (startIndex = 1)
and
Last Page (startIndex = [totalRows](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/list#totalRows) - expected page size) .

One more note: in case if table is under streaming (has streaming buffer at a time you do list) `totalRows` can be not available - in this case you can use extra call to [Tables: get](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/get) API and get [numRows](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#numRows) instead

Comment: I am not using tables.list. I have query which has where clauses between two timestamps. Say for example all records between 8.00 am to 9.00 am. The total record count is constant here.

GetQueryResultsResponse queryResult = bigQueryService
     .jobs()
     .getQueryResults(
       queryResponse.getJobReference().getProjectId(),
       queryResponse.getJobReference().getJobId())
     .setPageToken(pageToken).execute();

Comment: I will check the startIndex and MaxResults combination. 
 I am not using tables.list. I have query which has where clauses to fetch records between two timestamps. Say for example all records between 8.00 am to 9.00 am. The total record count is constant and available  when the query completes.

Comment: Here is the code
`GetQueryResultsResponse queryResult = bigQueryService
     .jobs()
     .getQueryResults(
       queryResponse.getJobReference().getProjectId(),
       queryResponse.getJobReference().getJobId())
     .setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
if (queryResult != null) {
   pageToken = queryResult.getPageToken();  
   rows = queryResult.getRows();
while (iter != null && iter.hasNext()) {
    TableRow row = iter.next();
    count++;
    if (row != null) {
     // Doing something with the row.
    }`